# Visual Studio 2013 crash on start

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Yesterday I studied a little MVC5 before bed.

Today, I open Visual Studio 2013 and while loading, the following exception occurs:

[image]
[image]

**Exception Details**

System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Buffer cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer

I have already repaired Visual Studio and nothing has changed.
Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061028/visual-studio-2013-keeps-crashing-with-error-denev-exe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058257/visual-studio-2013-crashes-on-startup-no-updates-or-changes-made

Comment: Only the second is equal, and it is in more detail than mine.
Anyway, none have answers ... sad

Comment: [create a crash dump and analyze the dump with Windbg/DebugDiag2 Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Update 5 worked for me. However you need to be part of Dev Essentials in order to download this update.

https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202013%20Update%205

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be fixed now, although I see no confirmation on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46728392-212b-405e-aea0-2ab02f91cd1f/visual-studio-2013-crashes-on-startup?forum=visualstudiogeneral

I'm running VS2013 U3 and able to startup without issue. A colleague is able to run VS2013 as well.